# Google Speech to Text files bigger than 10MB

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use Google Speech to Text for long files (~100MB)

But even when I am using the code (adapted) from https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize

I get the following exception:

> Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.")

This is my code so far:

```
string convertedFile = WavUtils.WavUtils.EncodeToWav(filename);
Dictionary<string, long> wavData = WavUtils.WavUtils.GetWAVData(convertedFile);

var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
var longOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(
  new RecognitionConfig()
  {
    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
    SampleRateHertz = (int)wavData["sampleRateHz"],
    LanguageCode = LanguageCodes.English.UnitedStates
  },
  RecognitionAudio.FromFile(convertedFile));
longOperation = longOperation.PollUntilCompleted();

var response = longOperation.Result;
foreach (var result in response.Results)
{
  foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
  }
}
```

Is the maximum file size really 10MB even with LongRunningRecognize?

The original file is actually a MP3 from a recorded Webcast.
But from what I have read Google Speech to Text does not support MP3 as input. That is why I am converting it to Wav.

Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: I have uploaded the file into Google Cloud Storage, but how do I point my code to the file? Here is my stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707803/how-do-i-use-google-speech-api-to-access-a-file-in-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to upload your audio file to Google storage first.  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-csharp

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not see the part about the storage.

Comment: How do you get the code to point to the file in Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough of a reputation to add a comment to Daniel Brower's question, but the answer is to use

```
RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri("gs://my-bucket/my-file");
```

instead of

```
RecognitionAudio.FromFile(convertedFile));
```